# internal server error when defining allow/deny rules with meteor

Tags: meteor

I'd like to allow insertion when user has filled an input and the number of character of this input is 12 (for example) and deny otherwise. I defined a rule in my server as follows:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Mydata.allow ({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {

     if ( $("#id").val().length === 12 ) {
       return true ;
     } else {
      return false ;
     }
    }
   });

  }
```

where `Mydata` is the name of my `collection` which is not empty but with with this code, insertion of data always fails with an "Internal server error".

What should be the correct way to set up this specific rule?

Thks,

Comment: You should not be using jquery on the server I guess ...

Comment: you should be using allow/deny rules to check the model(data) changes, not the state of the webpage

Comment: Ok, so let's suppose the user disable javascript so then he is able to insert incorrect data in my database. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is not defined on the server. You need to get user input and insert a document on the client, and then examine the document on the server.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Mydata.insert({yourfield: $("#id").val()});

} if (Meteor.isServer) {

 Mydata.allow ({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
   return doc.yourfield && (doc.yourfield.length === 12);
  }
 });

}
```

Comment: I definitively like Meteor. thks

Comment: It only gets better :)